# Azure VM diagnostics for SQL server not showing in log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have enabled sql server as part of performance counters. but when I a check log analytics or under metrics or Monitor. I see nothing. does it take time for data to come through? or some more setting is required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK yes it does take some time of ~15 minutes. Before you verify SQL Perf related logs from Log Analytics, I would suggest you to double check whether SQLServer related performance counters are already added under YourLogAnalyticsWorkspaceName -> AdvancedSettings tile -> Data -> WindowsPerformanceCounters or not.

You may already be aware of this but as you are referring to VM level monitoring stuff so I would recommend you to read through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-overview) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-enable-overview) tutorials to understand about a new feature 'Virtual Machines (preview)' which is basically seen as a new tile under Azure Monitor.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!